# Is there an international vaccine registry where I can store all my vaccination records in one place?

Tags: international-travel, online-resources, health, vaccinations, communication

Most of my vaccine records are stored online in my Kaiser Permanente account, but I also got a set of travel vaccines when I was in Australia and Kaiser wouldn't add them to my account. If I keep getting more vaccines from different sources then it may become difficult to keep track of them. I'd like there to be one place where I can keep all my vaccination records but I haven't found anything like that on Google. Are there any websites that offer combined vaccination record services?

Comment: Your Kaiser doctor should be able to add these to your KP record as long as you have suitable proof that you have had them.  Mine certainly has.

Comment: Definitely not online, but the traditional way of recording vaccines for international travel has been the [Yellow Card](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Certificate_of_Vaccination_or_Prophylaxis) for decades. Not sure you can record any vaccine there, though, it’s more commonly used for vaccines they are required for entry in some countries/regions like Yellow Fever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

I've been looking for this for a while but nothing usable exists.

During the pandemic the  travel industry was pleading for something like this but no government entity or the WHO picked it up. In desperation they kicked off their own initiatives but this fizzled out.

The US choice of using a CDC card to document Covid vaccine is a case in point: A hand written piece of paper that can you can also just download and fill out yourself (regardless whether you got the shot or not). One of my entries even has the date wrong.

So if you have lived in different countries and worked with different medical providers, you just end up with a stack of hand written notes (in different languages too). You can ask your current provider to transcribe it all into a single "Yellow Card" ([https://www.amazon.com/International-Certificate-Vaccination-Prophylaxis-CDC/dp/B07K1H8D3X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K1H8D3X)). However our provider refused to transcribe anything they didn't administer themselves since they have no way of verifying that your existing documentation is actually factual and correct.

You can try transcribing it yourself, but you would have to fudge the signatures.